# android - okhttp Authenticator request retry not working

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, retrofit, okhttp, refresh-token

Hello we're working with `okhttp/retrofit` and `oauth2` in the authentication system, actually the `Authenticator` is triggered when an api endpoint returns UNAUTHORIZED and we get the new credentials successfully, but the problem is the authenticator not retrying the previously endpoint that returned UNAUTHORIZED in response,
this is what i did:

```
@Singleton
class RefreshTokenAuthenticator @Inject constructor(
    @Named(CURRENT_CREDENTIALS_PREFERENCES_NAME)
    private val userDataPreferences: SharedPreferences
) : okhttp3.Authenticator {

    var apiHolder: ApiHolder? = null
    private val json = Json { ignoreUnknownKeys = true }

    override fun authenticate(route: Route?, response: Response): Request? {
        val credentialsString = userDataPreferences.getString(
            USER_CREDENTIALS_KEY, USER_CREDENTIALS_KEY
        ) ?: ""
        var request: Request? = null
        val credentials: UserCredentials? = try {
            json.decodeFromString(
                UserCredentials.serializer(), credentialsString
            )
        } catch (e: SerializationException) {
            null
        }

        credentials?.let { userCredentials ->
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                try {
                    val refreshTokenResponse = apiHolder?.api?.refreshToken(userCredentials)
                    if (refreshTokenResponse?.isSuccessful == true) {
                        val responseBody = refreshTokenResponse.body()?.data
                        responseBody?.let { body ->
                            val userCredentialsJson = json.encodeToString(
                                UserCredentials.serializer(),
                                body
                            )
                            userDataPreferences.edit().putString(
                                USER_CREDENTIALS_KEY,
                                userCredentialsJson
                            ).apply()

                            request = response.request
                                .newBuilder()
                                .header("Authorization", "Bearer ${body.accessToken}")
                                .build()

                        }
                    } else {
                        request = null
                        //TODO: handle errors
                    }
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Timber.e(e)
                }
            }
        }

        return request
    }
}
```

and this is how i create the OkhttpClient:

```
////
return OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(defaultHeadersInterceptor)
            .addInterceptor(authorizationInterceptor)
            .addInterceptor(errorHandlingInterceptor)
            .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
            .addInterceptor(CurlInterceptor {
                Timber.d("Ok2Curl $it ")
            })
            .authenticator(refreshTokenAuthenticator)
            .build()
```

NB: the authorization Interceptor adds the Bearer token in every request if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to factor out the API calling and retrying code, and that the interceptor mechanism may not do what you want.

My [API Client](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.mobilesample.android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/authsamples/basicmobileapp/api/client/ApiClient.kt#L71) shows an alternative approach, and wraps okhttp, so that Android view models make API calls via a one liner, rather than using okhttp directly.

Answer (score 0):

As Gary Archer did mention, what you can do to accomplish the retry policy for your unathorized requests, just add another Interceptor as you have done with the previous ones already and make them repeat your call after a while - it is totally up to you what the retry policy will look like, but I can give you an small example of what can be done:

```
class RetryOnUnauthorizedInterceptor @Inject constructor(
    @DispatcherDefault private val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher
) : Interceptor {

    constructor() : this(Dispatchers.Default)

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val request = chain.request()
        val response = chain.proceed(request)
        val responseCode = response.code
        return if (responseCode == HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED) {
            retry(chain, request, response)
        } else response
    }

    private fun retry(chain: Interceptor.Chain, request: Request, previousResponse: Response): Response {
        var response = previousResponse
        var retryCount = 0
        val responseCodes = mutableListOf(response.code)
        do {
            response.close()
            runBlocking(dispatcher) {
                delay(RETRY_DELAY_MILLIS)
            }
            response = chain.proceed(request)
            responseCodes.add(response.code)
            retryCount++
        } while (response.code == HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED && retryCount < MAX_RETRY_COUNT)
        return response
    }

    companion object {
        private const val RETRY_DELAY_MILLIS = 2000L
        private const val MAX_RETRY_COUNT = 2
        private const val HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED = 401
    }
}
```

This one here is done with the Coroutines, but you can shape it to your async implementation.

Happy coding!